# Horizontal menu with disappearing items by resizing

Tags: jquery, menu

everyone. I'm looking for JS plugin that makes horizontal menu with effect like this:

[horizontal menu](https://meb-online.ru/)

By resizing (reduce window width) item for which thete is no space disappiers and adds to droppdown menu.
Can someone advise how to make such an effect?

I'll be very grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this solution:

[description](http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Responsive-Horizontal-Nav-Menu-with-jQuery-CSS.html)

[Demo](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-Horizontal-Nav-Menu-with-jQuery-CSS/)